# Vapor4 Content (Codable) always decodes into empty result

Tags: swift, codable, vapor

I've detected a strange decoding behaviour in my Vapor 4 application.

We have an endpoint which accepts a simple JSON as a query parameter:

```
/api/debug/filter?where=%7B%20%22or%22:%20%5B%7B%20%22amount%22:%20%7B%20%22gte%22:%20%220%22%20%7D%20%7D,%20%7B%20%22amount%22:%20%7B%20%22lte%22:%20100%20%7D%20%7D%5D%7D&sort=amount%20ASC&limit=10&offset=0
```

Here the 'where'-parameter would be:
`{ "or": [{ "amount": { "gte": "0" } }, { "amount": { "lte": 100 } }]}`

Here is the Controller Class:

```
import Vapor

struct DebugController: RouteCollection {
    func boot(routes: RoutesBuilder) throws {
        routes.group("debug") { (debug) in
            debug.get("filter", use: debugFilter)
        }
    }
    
    
    private func debugFilter(_ req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<HTTPStatus> {
        log.debug(req.query)
        let whereString = try req.query.get(String.self, at: "where")
        let whereValue = try req.query.get(Where.self, at: "where")
        log.debug("Input String: \(whereString)")
        log.debug("Input Value: \(whereValue)")
        
        let filter = try req.query.decode(Filter.self)
        let `where` = try req.query.decode(Where.self)
        log.debug("Filter: \(filter)")
        log.debug("Where: \(`where`)")
        
        return req.eventLoop.makeSucceededFuture(()).transform(to: .ok)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
21:23:31.844  DEBUG DebugController.debugFilter():19 - _URLQueryContainer(request: GET /api/debug/filter?where=%7B%20%22or%22:%20%5B%7B%20%22amount%22:%20%7B%20%22gte%22:%20%220%22%20%7D%20%7D,%20%7B%20%22amount%22:%20%7B%20%22lte%22:%20100%20%7D%20%7D%5D%7D&sort=amount%20ASC&limit=10&offset=0 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.193 Safari/537.36
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.7
)
21:23:31.857  DEBUG DebugController.debugFilter():22 - Input String: { "or": [{ "amount": { "gte": "0" } }, { "amount": { "lte": 100 } }]}
21:23:31.857  DEBUG DebugController.debugFilter():23 - Input Value: and([])
21:23:31.857  DEBUG DebugController.debugFilter():27 - Filter: Filter(where: Optional(App.Where.and([])), sort: Optional([App.Sort(key: "amount", direction: App.Sort.Direction.ascending)]), limit: Optional(10), offset: Optional(0))
21:23:31.858  DEBUG DebugController.debugFilter():28 - Where: and([])
```

The Codable for this payload is the following, which resolved very well in the past:

```
public indirect enum Where: Codable {
    case expression(String, ExpressionRelation, Any?)
    case and([Where])
    case or([Where])
        
    public enum ConjunctionKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case or
        case and
    }

    public enum ExpressionRelation: String {
        case gt
        case gte
        case lt
        case lte
        case like
        case eq
        case isNull
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let conjunctionContainer = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: ConjunctionKeys.self)
         
        // result is: [:] no matter what input was given, strange. 
        if let and = try? conjunctionContainer?.decode([Where].self, forKey: .and) {
            self = .and(and)
            return
        }
        
        // result is: [:] no matter what input was given, strange.
        if let or = try? conjunctionContainer?.decode([Where].self, forKey: .or) {
            self = .or(or)
            return
        }
        
        // result is: [:] no matter what input was given, strange.
        if let expressionContainer = try? decoder.singleValueContainer() {
            if let expression = try? expressionContainer.decode([String: [String: String]].self),
                let key = expression.keys.first,
                let relationContainer = expression[key],
                let relationKey = relationContainer.keys.first,
                let relation = ExpressionRelation(rawValue: relationKey),
                let value = relationContainer[relation.rawValue]
            {
                self = .expression(key, relation, value)
                return
            }

            if let expression = try? expressionContainer.decode([String: [String: Double]].self),
                let key = expression.keys.first,
                let relationContainer = expression[key],
                let relationKey = relationContainer.keys.first,
                let relation = ExpressionRelation(rawValue: relationKey),
                let value = relationContainer[relation.rawValue]
            {
                self = .expression(key, relation, value)
                return
            }
                       
            if let expression = try? expressionContainer.decode([String: [String: Int]].self),
                let key = expression.keys.first,
                let relationContainer = expression[key],
                let relationKey = relationContainer.keys.first,
                let relation = ExpressionRelation(rawValue: relationKey),
                let value = relationContainer[relation.rawValue]
            {
                self = .expression(key, relation, value)
                return
            }
        }
        
        throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Unable to decode", underlyingError: nil))
    }
    
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        
        switch self {
        case .and(let and):
            var conjunctionContainer = encoder.container(keyedBy: ConjunctionKeys.self)
            try conjunctionContainer.encode(and, forKey: .and)
        case .or(let or):
            var conjunctionContainer = encoder.container(keyedBy: ConjunctionKeys.self)
            try conjunctionContainer.encode(or, forKey: .or)
        case .expression(let key, let relation, let value):
            var singleValueContainer = encoder.singleValueContainer()
            
            switch value {
            case is String:
                try singleValueContainer.encode([key: [relation.rawValue: value as! String]])
            case is Double:
                try singleValueContainer.encode([key: [relation.rawValue: value as! Double]])
            case is Int:
                try singleValueContainer.encode([key: [relation.rawValue: value as! Int]])
            default: break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here ist that every `.decode()` call returns `[:]` and not `nil` and therefor The decoded content ist always `and([])` no matter what input was given.

The strange thing is it runs very well in a Playground within the project:
[image: Playground]

- There are no custom JSONDecoders configured in the project.
- I'm using latest xCode: Version 11.7 (11E801a)

Here are the used packages:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.2
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "backend",
    platforms: [
       .macOS(.v10_15)
    ],
    dependencies: [
        //  A server-side Swift web framework.
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", from: "4.35.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent.git", from: "4.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent-postgres-driver.git", from: "2.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/jwt.git", from: "4.0.0-rc.2"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/iLem0n/SwiftyBeaver.git", .exact("1.8.4")),
        .package(url: "../SwiftSpec", .branch("master")),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/Maxim-Inv/SwiftDate.git", .branch("master")),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/queues.git", from: "1.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/queues-redis-driver.git", from: "1.0.0-rc.1"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/dehesa/CodableCSV", from: "0.6.2")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "App",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "Fluent", package: "fluent"),
                .product(name: "FluentPostgresDriver", package: "fluent-postgres-driver"),
                .product(name: "Vapor", package: "vapor"),
                .product(name: "JWT", package: "jwt"),
                .product(name: "SwiftyBeaver", package: "SwiftyBeaver"),                
                .product(name: "SwiftDate", package: "SwiftDate"),
                .product(name: "SwiftSpec", package: "SwiftSpec"),
                .product(name: "CodableCSV", package: "CodableCSV"),
                .product(name: "Queues", package: "queues"),
                .product(name: "QueuesRedisDriver", package: "queues-redis-driver")
            ],
            swiftSettings: [
                // Enable better optimizations when building in Release configuration. Despite the use of
                // the `.unsafeFlags` construct required by SwiftPM, this flag is recommended for Release
                // builds. See <https://github.com/swift-server/guides#building-for-production> for details.
                .unsafeFlags(["-cross-module-optimization"], .when(configuration: .release))
            ]
        ),
        .target(name: "Run", dependencies: [.target(name: "App")]),
        .testTarget(name: "AppTests", dependencies: [
            .target(name: "App"),
            .product(name: "XCTVapor", package: "vapor"),
        ])
    ]
)
```

Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong or where I can continue with debugging ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form Decoding is not the same as JSON Decoding. So you're mixing two different formats, which is the source of the problem. I would recommend not trying to put JSON inside a query because you're always going to hit upon edge cases and decoding issues.

However, if you have to you're almost there. What you need to do is get the raw String (which converts the URL encoded string into a JSON string) then manually decode that yourself with `JSONDecoder` - that should give you the desired result.